# groovy MySQLSyntaxErrorException with CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, groovy

I don't understand why or how I can possibly be getting a syntax error here. Here is the code:

```
def dbname = "liberalgeek_wp"
def dbinfo = [url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql', user: dbuser, password: dbpass, driver: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver']
println("db info: ${dbinfo}\n\n")

def db = Sql.newInstance(dbinfo.url, dbinfo.user, dbinfo.password, dbinfo.driver)

def create_db_sql = "create database if not exists ${dbname}"
println("sql: ${create_db_sql}\n\n")
db.execute(create_db_sql)
```

Here is the output when I run it:

```
db info: [url:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql, user:kenny, password:xxxxxx, driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]

sql: create database if not exists liberalgeek_wp

Mar 18, 2017 4:03:59 PM groovy.sql.Sql execute
WARNING: Failed to execute: create database if not exists ? because: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''liberalgeek_wp'' at line 1
Caught: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''liberalgeek_wp'' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''liberalgeek_wp'' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
    at setup_wordpress.createMySQLDatabase(setup_wordpress.groovy:125)
```

I can't imagine what syntax error that command could possibly have, so I opened my command line and logged in to mysql using the same user/pass credentials that my groovy script is using. I copy/pasted the command into mysql and it worked just fine:

```
Kenny-iMac:~$ mysql -ukenny -p mysql
Enter password: xxxxxx

mysql> create database if not exists liberalgeek_wp;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to execute this statement using `prepared statements`. However, DDL instructions (such as create database) are not allowed within prepared statements, because a database name can't be bound to a variable.

What you can do in that particular case: Build your query directly without using a prepared statement.

I have to be more precise in this: In fact: DDL statements *are* allowed in prepared statements, *but* you can't bind variables to names such as database, table or column names. You can, however, bind variables to other things such as default values or maybe even setup parameter values, although i didn't test that.

Comment: Fascinating. I used @Mike W's code below and it worked well, but I was trying to figure out WHY it worked when mine failed and your answer gave me the indicator so I've accepted it as the real answer. It turns out that when using a GString, the Sql class parses the GString to extract the variables and builds a prepared statement out of it, and as he said, queries that alter the DDL aren't allowed to be prepared statements. So, I didn't KNOW I was using a prepared statement behind the scenes. The error message (containing a ?) makes SO much more sense now.

Comment: That's how i deduced the prepared statement: A `?` within a syntax error nearly always indicates a not properly resolved, prepared statement in mysql

Answer (score 1):

Use executeUpdate rather than execute and don't use GString in the call, resolve the string prior to this, think this is to protect against SQL injection.

```
....
def create_db_sql = 'create database if not exists ' + dbname
println("sql: ${create_db_sql}\n\n")

db.executeUpdate( create_db_sql )
....
```

Tested using MySQL version 5.7.17

Comment: Fascinating. This code worked well, thank you for that. I was trying to figure out WHY it worked when mine failed and @Psi's answer gave me the indicator. It turns out that when using a GString, the Sql class parses the GString to extract the variables and builds a prepared statement out of it, and as he said, queries that alter the DDL aren't allowed to be prepared statements.